.Net Core SignalR Connection between services has an issue
I have several services communicating with each other via SignalR connection. They are both standard .net core web api services, let's say I have service A and service B.
Service A has SignalR hub configured and accepting connections, Service B is connected to it using HubConnection class from Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client package. And is listening to some messages from service A with: hubConnection.On('...')
Service B also has a signalR Hub and is accepting connections from website clients.
Service A is sending about 2000 messages in a minute to service B, and service B also streams these messages to all the connected clients. there are about 80 client connections to service B at the same time.
The issue is that the messages from Service A are arriving very late, they are about 2 minutes late. I am logging the line when the message is sent from service A and is received in service B and it's about 2 minute difference. I don't have any ideas why this happens, 2k messages in a minute isn't that much as I Believe.
here's a diagram:

Service B does this type of logic on each received message:
hubConnection.On(method.Name, parameterTypes, @params =>
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var activity = new Activity("HubListener");
        try
        {
            activity.Start();
            activity.AddTag("TraceId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            activity.AddTag("ArrivalTime", DateTime.UtcNow);

            var obj = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(method.DeclaringType)
            method.Invoke(obj, @params);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e, "Error In Hub Listener");

        }
        finally
        {
            activity.Stop();
        }
    });
});

the method is taken via reflection from my BroadcastService class (there are other methods too that's why use reflection to subscribe dynamically):
public class BroadcastService {
        private readonly IHubContext<BaseHub> _baseHubContext;

        public BroadcastService(IHubContext<BaseHub> baseHubContext)
        {
            _baseHubContext = baseHubContext ?? BaseHub.CurrentContext;
        }

        public void BroadcastToClients(Message messageFromServiceA)
        {
             // it takes about 2 minutes for message to arrive at this place after it is sent from Service A.
             // clients are separated in groups
             foreach(var group in clientGroups){
          _baseHubContext
             .Clients
             .Group(group.Name)
             .SendAsync("onMessage",messageFromServiceA)
          }
        }
}

If I run service B on local machine and there are no connections from clients the messages are not delayed, this has something to do with number of client connections but 80 is not a lot. I don't know if the messages on hubConnection are executed sequentially, but this should not be an issue because I use Task.Run and this should run handler asynchronously.
I would appreciate any kind of help, I will edit the question if more details are required.

Hi Rezga, please try to enable asp.net core signalr client logging in your server B, and you also can enable server logging in Server A.

Thanks Jason, will try to see if some clues are being logged

Hello Rezga, please also try to use async ,not void.

I finally found answer to my question, the issue was that SignalR client (as well as server) processes messages sequentially, I understood this by logging start and end timestamps of the handlers. After some research I found out that this was by design in SignalR Core, here's similar question and answer.
To fix my issue I just run task in background and don't wait for it:
old code:
hubConnection.On(method.Name, parameterTypes, @params =>
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        ...
    });
});

new code:
hubConnection.On(method.Name, parameterTypes, @params =>
{
    _ = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        ...
    });

    return Task.CompletedTask;
});

Now it works just fine.
